# Pulling a div element with Beautifulsoup that has no class, name, or id

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am starting to introduce myself with BeautifulSoup, and trying to pull data from a website, after pulling it I need to get a "div" element but the div element has no class.
Ex: looking for text in `<div grea><div>` in a HTML file like this one using BeautifulShoup.
When fished it should return the value "Book Wishes" from down below from the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=
    , initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="static\blogo.png">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Nunito:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/color.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/cooc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/pics/css/all.css">



</head>
<body>

    <nav class="nav-top-bar">
        <li class="nav-img">
            <img src="/static/blogo.png" class="logo">
            
        </li>
        <li class="nav-btn">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-btn">
            <a href="/donate">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-btn">
            <a href="/login">Teacher login</a>
        </li>
    </nav>
    <h2 class="bb"> </h2>
    
    <div class="main">
        <div grea>
            <h1>Book Wishes</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="gre">
            <h1><i>Find a new home for your used books.

                <br>Donate wished-for books to classroom libraries at Blanchard.</i></h1>
                <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
        <a href="/donate" class="button">Donate</a>     

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="WHAT">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="box1">
            <a>Make room on your 
                <br> bookshelf for new 
                <br> favorites!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cardim1">
            <img class="imm" src="static/face.png" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="box2">
            <a>Give your old book new life by sharing it with the whole classroom!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cardim2">
            <img class="imm" src="static/light.png" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
        <div class="box4">
            <a>Why donate</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box3">
            <a>Help teachers create the 
                <br>classroom library of their 
                <br>dreams!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cardim3">
            <img class="imm" src="static/head.png" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div id="myModal" class="modal-content">
        <p class = "tt">This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our website.</p>
        <a class = "ttt" href="/privacy">Learn more</a> 
        <span class="cclose">Got it!</span>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("cclose")[0];
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        localStorage.setItem('cookieSeen', 'shown')

    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('cookieSeen') != 'shown') {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first select the `div` with the `main` class, using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div_main = soup.find("div", {"class": "main"})
```

You can then select the text within `h1` tag using `div_main.find("h1").text`.

Combine the two steps into a single line like this

```
output = soup.find("div", {"class": "main"}).find("h1").text
#Book Wishes
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the div doesn't have any other elements to go off of, you should try and find a different way of retrieving it. The easier thing to do would be to find all the H1s since your payload is in an H1 tag.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
h1s = soup.find_all('h1')
```

This will return two values:

```
[<h1>Book Wishes</h1>, <h1><i>Find a new home for your used books.

                <br/>Donate wished-for books to classroom libraries at Blanchard.</i></h1>]
```

From there, you can just use `h1s[0].text` to extract the text of the first item in the list.